# Hiding toolbar in fragment causes blinking

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-jetpack-navigation

I am using Jetpack Navigation and i have MainActivity. There are a lot of fragments in this activity, toolbars in all of these fragments are the same.

But one fragment is about searching something, so i implemented custom toolbar in that fragment ( like i put an search bar inside toolbar, and did some other customizations)

Now when i switch to search fragment i need to hide main toolbar and show the custom toolbar (one i defines in search fragment layout)

I did this with code below

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { navController: NavController, navDestination: NavDestination, bundle: Bundle? ->
     if (navDestination.id == R.id.searchFragment) {
          binding.toolbarMainActivity.visibility = View.GONE
     } else {
         if (binding.toolbarMainActivity.visibility == View.GONE) {
            binding.toolbarMainActivity.visibility = View.VISIBLE
         }
     }
}
```

[image: problem gif]

As you can see there is a slight glimpse of toolbar, how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: hi dear,could you show me your layout's code?Seems like its your layout code cause your issue

Comment: https://codeshare.io/axyEVX -- it is search fragment layout code
https://codeshare.io/5RjJX4 --  and it is activity main layout code